# Post request pending on MERN

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm trying to learn the MERN stack. I'm creating my first very simple site. Now, I created a route where I create an user, using the datas passed throw body. Here is the code of the server:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();


const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser:true });

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () =>{
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established succesfully")
})

const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users', usersRouter); 

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Now, here is the code of the users router file, into i put the code:

```
const router = require('express').Router();//setting it as a express router
let User = require('../models/user.model');//requise the model created before

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  User.find()//mongoose method, returns a promise
    .then(users => res.json(users))//return the list of user
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;

  const newUser = new User({username});

  newUser.save()
    .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

And, in the end, here is the model user schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


//create the schema for the user
//like the model in Flask
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 3
    },
},{
    timestamps:true,
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema); //create the model, via the schema

module.exports = User;
```

Now, to test if it is correct, before implement other code and the frontend, I would like to test it out. First I would like to add a new user, to see if the API works properly. I'm using postman. I sent the request on this URL: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/add`, with the following json in the body:`{"username": "name"}`. Then I send, but Postman continue to say me that it is sending the request, and it continues for minutes. I can't understand if the problem is the promise, that is too low, if I wrote something incorrectly in the code or in the test configuration, if there are issues with the Mongo database, or anything else. Can you help me please? Thanks

Comment: it is `app.use(cors())` not `app.use(cors)`

Comment: always use a logger like [`morgan`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) or other libraries to log requests.

Comment: seems like you are not sending any response back from your server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your DB connection  you are not waiting for the `promise` to be `resolved`

```
    require('dotenv').config();
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    
    const connectDB = async () => {
      try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.ATLAS_URI, {
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
          useNewUrlParser: true,
        });
    
        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error: ${err.message}`);
        process.exit(1);
      }
    };
    
    
    connectDB()
    
    
    const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
    app.use('/users', usersRouter); 
    
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
    });
```